# Linq para base de datos con Genericos C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, linq, genericos

Buen día, una consulta, estoy implementando Generic Repository y tengo los modelos cuya clave primaria se nombran como prefijoId dónde el prefijo varía osea que tendría (ParametroID , EmpresaId, SucursalId, ClienteId) en las distintas tablas.

A la hora de hacer un firstOrDefault  debería ser algo así:

```
public TEntity GetByIdAsync(long id){                        
        var entity =  _context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id );
        return entity;
```

}

Como ven debería reemplazar el c.Id por prefijoId  pero como estoy recibiendo un generíco no sé cómo hacerlo ya que para cada genérico que se me pase tendré un nombre diferente .

Me pueden ayudar?

Gracias

Comment: Puedes añadir un mensaje de error para tener más claridad?

Comment: Puedes dar mas detalles, para entenderte mejor

Comment: Tienes un clase TEntity??? puedes exponerla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es una posible aproximación:

**Método 1**, Crear una interfaz que implemente un método (Property) con el nombre del campo.

Por ejemplo:

```
public interface TIEntity // Type Interface Entity
{
  public int prefijoId {get;set;} // Todas las entidades implementan la propiedad
                                  // que indexa las llaves primarias.
}
                // Aquí está la clave, TIEntity debe heredar de 
class Foo<TEntity> where TEntity : TIEntity
{
 //Contra, debes , Implementar la Propiedad prefijoId, esto atenta con el principio Open/Closed Principle, pero sí el proyecto es nuevo amerita que sea implementado.
 public TEntity GetByIdAsync(long id)
  {                        
   var entity =  _context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking()
       .FirstOrDefault(c => c.prefijoId == id );
        return entity;
   }
}
```

**Método 2** , Implementar Reflection.

```
 public TEntity GetByIdAsync(long id)
  {                        
   var entity =  _context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking()
       .FirstOrDefault(c => {
            // En este bloque debes preguntar sí el tipo de c
            var primaryKeyProperty = c.GetType().GetProperty("prefijoId");

            // Se debe validar, que la llave sea pública.
            if(primaryKeyProperty!=null)
            {
               var pkValue = c.GetType().GetProperty("prefijoId").GetValue(c, null);
               return pkValue == id;
            } 
            else
            {
               return false;
            }
            // Preguntar si existe la propiedad 
        } );
        return entity;
   }
```